# How to call a callback from a conditional async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given this code:

```
var something = function(callback) {

  if(condition) {
     Mongoose.findOne(id, function(err, doc) {
       if(doc) {
         callback(doc);
       } else {
         callback();
       }
    });
  } else {
    callback();
  }
}
```

How would I rewrite it in a cleaner way so that 'callback' is just called in one place. I assume I can wrap this entire thing somehow and do that - I've seen it but cannot get it quite right.

Comment: this code is fine as it is.

Comment: This question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com but why not get rid of the `if (doc) {...` and just do `callback(doc)`? Does your callback look at `arguments.length`? If so, then you could do `callback.apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments, 1))` if you really want.

Comment: I guess my issue is this - my callback call in reality contains more code - while I know this works I know that there is a way to wrap this entire inner part inside of another function and return from that. But just can't remember how

Comment: why can't you write another wrapper method called `callCallback` where you put all the code related to calling the `callback` and then call that method from all the three places with necessary parameters

Answer (score 1):

Since you said there are complex steps to call the callback, try the below

```
var something = function(callback) {
    var callCallback = function(doc){
        //do all other things you want to do to call the callback
        callback(doc);
    };

    if(condition) {
        Mongoose.findOne(id, function(err, doc) {
            if(doc) {
                callCallback(doc);
            } else {
                callCallback();
            }
        });
    } else {
        callCallback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var something = function (callback) {
  var f = function (e, d) { callback(d) };

  if (condition) {
     Mongoose.findOne(id, f);
  } else {
    f();
  }
}
```

my reasoning is that if `d` is `false` then we still can pass it on to `callback` and it will be the same almost as passing no arguments at all.